# Information from form will not submit to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

Thank you for taking the time to read this.  I am using an HTML form and submitting information to a MySQL database through it, using PHP.  I can not figure out why the information is not making it into the database though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what the database looks like:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/1N9lczN.png]

This is the HTML form:

```
<?php ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Raid Boss Strategy Editor</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h3>Raid Strats</h3>

        <p>
            <form action="stratadd2.php" method="POST">
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="4" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Boss Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bossName" value="<?php echo "$bossName"; ?>"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Raid Zone</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="raidZone" value="<?php echo "$raidZone"; ?>"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Boss Health</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bossHealth" value="<?php echo "$bossHealth"; ?>"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Boss Enrage</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bossEnrage" value="<?php echo "$bossEnrage"; ?>"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Boss Abilities</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bossAbilities" value="<?php echo "$bossAbilities"; ?>"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phase One</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bossPhaseone" value="<?php echo "$bossPhaseone"; ?>"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phase Two</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bossPhasetwo" value="<?php echo "$bossPhasetwo"; ?>"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phase Three</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bossPhasethree" value="<?php echo "$bossPhasethree"; ?>"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Final Notes</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="finalNotes" value="<?php echo "$finalNotes"; ?>"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbc.php';
error_reporting(0);

if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $bossName = $_POST['bossName'];
    $raidZone = $_POST['raidZone'];
    $bossHealth = $_POST['bossHealth'];
    $bossEnrage = $_POST['bossEnrage'];
    $bossAbilities = $_POST['bossAbilities'];
    $bossPhaseone = $_POST['bossPhaseone'];
    $bossPhasetwo = $_POST['bossPhasetwo'];
    $bossPhasethree = $_POST['bossPhasethree'];
    $finalNotes = $_POST['finalNotes'];

    require "dbc.php";
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO raidstrats VALUES ('','$bossName','$raidZone','$bossHealth','$bossEnrage','$bossAbilities','$bossPhaseone','$bossPhasetwo','$bossPhasethree','$finalNotes')");
    die("Information Submitted!");
}
?>
```

Comment: You have a lot of securityholes in your code. I suggest you read about mysql injection, and PDO.

Comment: Why `require_once 'dbc.php';` and `require "dbc.php";`?

Comment: Hi Fred,  removing either of them doesn't appear to change anything, but you're right it is unnecessary.

Thank you for the advice Luc Prevoo.

Comment: turn `error_reporting()` on : test for `$query` : we can not see your connection inside `dbc.php`.

Comment: <?php

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","aimeriserver","edited out") or die("Unable to connect to the database server!");;
mysql_select_db("aimeriserver_ast") or die ("Unable to find the database!");;

?>

Answer (score 1):

Probably to do with inserting an empty string ('') into an autoincrement index column (Id). Try specifying the column names

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO raidstrats (bossName,raidZone,bossHealth,bossEnrage,bossAbilities,bossPhaseone,bossPhasetwo,bossPhasethree,finalNotes) VALUES ('$bossName','$raidZone','$bossHealth','$bossEnrage','$bossAbilities','$bossPhaseone','$bossPhasetwo','$bossPhasethree','$finalNotes')");
```

Comment: Just attempted this and it didn't seem to change anything.  Thank you very much though!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once 'dbc.php';
error_reporting(0);

if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $bossName = $_POST['bossName'];
    $raidZone = $_POST['raidZone'];
    $bossHealth = $_POST['bossHealth'];
    $bossEnrage = $_POST['bossEnrage'];
    $bossAbilities = $_POST['bossAbilities'];
    $bossPhaseone = $_POST['bossPhaseone'];
    $bossPhasetwo = $_POST['bossPhasetwo'];
    $bossPhasethree = $_POST['bossPhasethree'];
    $finalNotes = $_POST['finalNotes'];

    require "dbc.php";
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO raidstrats VALUES (NULL,$bossName, $raidZone, $bossHealth, $bossEnrage, $bossAbilities, $bossPhaseone, $bossPhasetwo', $bossPhasethree,  $finalNotes)");
    die("Information Submitted!");
}
?>
```

Comment: Just attempted this and it didn't seem to change anything.  Thank you very much though!